# How to create rectangle icon button without label in flutter?

Tags: button, flutter

we can create the icon button with `FlatButton.icon()` but it requires `label` parameter.
we can also use `IconButton()` but it makes a circular icon button.

how to make a rectangle icon button like `FlatButton()` but with just icon in flutter?

Comment: just use FlatButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), minWidth: 0, )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Container(
  height: 100.0,
  width: 100.0,
  child: FlatButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.place),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
),
```

Comment: I see no rectangle button there, it just shows a (pretty big) rectangle when you clock on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a container with an icon as a child and wrap the container with the InkWell widget to make it clickable. This way you can shape your container to your need, which in this case is a rectangle.

Here's a code sample -

```
InkWell(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              border: Border.all(
                width: 1,
              )),
          child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black),
        ),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Inkwell combination with container you can make customized button easily as done in above example

```
InkWell(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              border: Border.all(
                width: 1,
              )),
          child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black),
        ),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
```